# Isolate part of a string from index to next whitespace?

Tags: javascript, string

What's the best way to do this solve for this next whitespace?

```
var string = 'hi this is a string with some !things in it"
var index = string.indexOf('!')
var afterbang = string.substring(index, [NEXT SPACE])
```

result: things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the whole thing with a regular expression:

```
var afterbang = string.replace(/.*!(\S*).*/, "$1");
```

What that does is match an exclamation point, followed by some amount of non-whitespace (that's what `\S` means — `\s` with a lower-case "s" matches whitespace, and upper-case "s" is the opposite).  The non-whitespace match is parenthesized so that the regex matching process collects that portion of the match. Finally, the second parameter to `.replace()` indicates that the first matched group should be returned, which will be that collection of non-whitespace characters right after the first exclamation point.

*edit* — sorry for the error - fixed now. The original code I typed in would leave you with all the rest of the string too, removing only the exclamation point :-)  I've updated it to include leading and trailing `.*` expressions to make sure we get rid of everything else.

If you need to find all such substrings (that is, all occurrences of "!" followed by some non-whitespace characters) then things get a little more complicated.  Personally, I would exploit the fact that JavaScript allows a function to be passed as the second argument of `.replace()`. When you do that, the matched groups are passed as arguments to the function:

```
var collection = [];
string.replace(/!(\S*)/g, function(_, bangWord) {
  collection.push(bangWord);
});
```

After that, the array "collection" will contain all the matches. The suffix "g" on the regular expression causes the match to be done over and over until it's no longer found in the string, starting each time after the previous match.

(The function has a dummy first parameter, called "_", that's just a placeholder. The first parameter to the function is always the entire match from the whole regular expression. The second and subsequent arguments are from the parenthesized groups. Thus, in this case, the first argument would be the string *including* the exclamation point, and the second argument is just the substring without it.)

Comment: this looks great, do you mind just breaking it down a bit so I can apply it outside of this example?

Comment: @boom done - I encourage you to look around for introductions and tutorials on regular expressions. It's an extremely powerful mechanism in JavaScript and many other programming environments.

Comment: is there an easy path from this to find not just first instance of the `!` say if there were multiple `!`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. Won't this just make the string be: "hi this is a string with some things in it"

Comment: @aquinas ah yes - darn I typed it in correctly the first time but screwed up and erased it - I'll fix it.

Comment: @boom I'll update the answer again on that point (multiple occurrences).

Comment: @boom OK it's updated now - sorry for the delay; I had to take a phone call :-)

Comment: @pointy thanks so much! you don't have to answer this follow, i already marked your answer right -- but i just was thinking about accommodating more endings (white space, comma, and line end) can you combine things like this easily or would i use separate regexs

Comment: @boom yes there are ways of doing that - regular expressions can't do *everything* of this nature, but they're a pretty powerful tool. It can get a little involved so it make make for a good question on its own. You can get more information [online](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) about regular expressions. (That site looks a little cheesy but the information is OK.)

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = "hi this is a string with some !things in it";
var index = s.indexOf('!')
var afterbang = s.substring(index, s.indexOf(' ', index));

​
```

I'm actually assuming you already have a particular start index that you care about. If that's not the case, then a regex makes more sense:

```
var s = "hi this is a string with some !things in it";
var afterbang = s.match(/!.+?\s+/);
alert(afterbang)
​
```

Comment: ah this works great once i added global `/!.+?\s+/g` how would I do white space or end of the string with that regex though?

Comment: also I would like to trim out the starting `#` and ending `' '` -- just learning regexs

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're going for. Can you give an example input/output?

Comment: sorry, i'm mixing my examples, input = `hi this is a string with some !things !things2, !things3` ----> output = `[things, things2, things3]

Comment: basically I want to accommodate all instances and endings including `' '` `,` and `line end`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but, if you mean simply getting this over and over again:

```
var substrings = [];
    string = SOME STRING HERE,
    index = string.indexOf('!'),
    nextWhiteIndex,
    stringToBePushed;

while (index !== -1) {

    stringToBePush = string.slice(index + 1);
    if (stringToBePush.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
        nextWhiteIndex = stringToBePushed.indexOf(' ');
        substrings.push(stringToBePushed.substring(0, nextWhiteIndex + 1);
    } else if (stringToBePushed !== '') {
        substrings.push(stringToBePushed.substring(0);
    }

    index = string.indexOf('!');
}
```

EDIT: Now I know what you want. This will simply get you all the words immediately after exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var s = "hi this is a string with some !things in it";
var re = /(.*)!([^ ]*)/; // regex capturing two groups split over '!'
var m = re.exec(s); 
WScript.Echo(m[2]);      // take second match
```

or without regex;

```
var a = s.split('!');    // split in half
var b = a[1].split(' '); // split in half again, taking second half
WScript.Echo(b[0]);      // show first half
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use this -

```
allText.slice(startIndex).trim().split(' ')[0]
```

This will splice the entire text before your startIndex,
then using split, you find the next space and take the first index.
You'll get your expected word.